# Calculating the curvature of a dataframe

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following data frame that when plotted looks like this:
[image]

I would like to visualise the curvature (slope?) of the dotted line. So that I get a flat line where there is not much chance in the curvature and a peak when the curvature increases, regardless it is concave or convex. I prototyped the following image as a test:

[image]

So the blue area at the bottom of the image is probably close to what I am trying to achieve. I have already researched the topic a bit, it seems like the `numpy.gradient()` function should be used. But I am not sure how to implement this.

Once I come up with the calculation, I can find a way to visualise this in `plotly`, the bit I do not understand is the calculation.

I would like to apologies is advance, if this is duplicate of this question: [Curve curvature in numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28269379/curve-curvature-in-numpy)

What is confusing about the answer for that question is that although it is a detailed answer, there are many different bits being calculated on that post and I am having difficult times choosing the one that might help me in my case.

**--- EDIT ---**

I would do this in the following way, as a prototype, inside a platform that I am more familiar with:

[image]

So in this image, I am looking at the next tangent and the previous tangent, if the angle between those tangents is high (the dot product, closer to 0) the curvature is high, if the angle is at a lower level (the dot product closer to 1), there is less curvature. I am asking how to achieve this in Python using `numpy` or a similar framework.

Comment: This is quite unclear, if yourself don't know what you want, how could we? If you want the curvature it is simply defined as the double derivative, i.e. the gradient of the gradient. If you want the slope, it is simply the gradient. Then the computation is straight forward... and if you care only about the magnitude, then just take the `abs`.

Comment: I am after this: the region of the plotted line, that is less volatile, meaning no change in direction, should yield a value close to 0 and the regions where we observe up or down movement, thus being volatile should yield values closer to 1.

Comment: "less volatile" is your own jargon. This is not a programming question, it is about putting a clear mathematical definition on a vague concept you have in your mind. It is your job to come up with the definition you want...

Comment: So what's wrong with the curvature as usually defined: gradient of gradient?

Comment: Nothing, probably that is what I need. What would be the way to calculate it. I guess, I am used to the context of `position` -> `velocity` -> `acceleration` and my curve is `change in price`. This is where I got confused. How I calculate the gradient of a gradient?

Comment: hmm... that's a hard question...  what about `np.gradient(np.gradient(my_data))`?

Comment: I will try that, however, did you have a chance to check the other question I am referring to in my question. The author of the answer is using `np.gradient` but in a more elaborate way. I am wondering if there is something else to this that might make it slightly more complicated that we initially thought.