# Detecting Curvature of a Plot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I have a data set that I am plotting. The result looks like the following image:
[image]

Here is my python code:

```
import numpy as np

# Extra plotly bits
import plotly
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go

a = np.array([[1, 0.00617329], [24, 0.133699], [48, 0.130072], [72, 0.0166202], [96, -0.187917], [120, -0.445023], [144, -0.698984],
    [168, -0.942063], [192, -1.15151], [216, -1.30742], [240, -1.36852], [264, -1.33541], [288, -1.18194], [312, -0.982113],
    [336, -0.772301], [360, -0.562501], [384, -0.3764], [408, -0.219537], [432, -0.106257], [456, -0.0369356], [480, -0.000313192]])


trace_a = go.Scatter(
        x = a[:,0],
        y = a[:,1],
        mode = 'lines+markers',
        name = 'a',
        line = dict(
            shape='line',
            color = ('rgb(205, 12, 24)'),
            width = 1)
        )

data = [trace_a]

# Edit the layout
layout = dict(title = 'Curvature Test',
    xaxis = dict(title = 'Data'),
    yaxis = dict(title = 'Value'),
    )

# Prepare Figure
fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)

# Plot
plotly.offline.plot(fig, filename='curvature.html')
```

What I am trying to achieve is adding an additional plot that traces the curvature of the primary plot.

That probably will look like the following image:
[image]

*(This is a prototype and the yellow markings are only to demonstrate that the second plot is representing the curvature of the first one.)*

Since I was not able to find the right numpy/maths solution I prototyped this in an other environment using a dot product calculation of the previous and next tangent for each of the data points. So this is my "Poor-Man's-Curvature" solution:

[image]

How can I create a second data set that once plotted will represent the curvature of the primary one?

**Disclaimer:**
I have asked this question before. However, did not manage to workout an elegant solution. I also have researched the topic of curvature and I am aware of the curvature calculations. Yet I am still struggling to put this together using python/numpy and the right mathematical approach. I also have spent some time on the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28269379/curve-curvature-in-numpy) but was not able to fully port the information provided there to solve my problem.

*--- EDIT (1) ---*

Here is the result of my solution:
[image]

Comment: taking a derivative of function and figuring out the slope of a tangent line that touches the J(θ) at given θ and If the slope is positive decrease in the next iteration to move closer to the minimum and put condition that if slope is negative increase a bit when it touch the tangent , i think that's what you are looking ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the curvature can be interpreted as the second derivative so:

```
def derivative(x_data, y_data):
    N = len(x_data)
    delta_x = [x_data[i+1] - x_data[i] for i in range(N - 1)]
    x_prim = [(x_data[i+1] + x_data[i]) / 2. for i in range(N - 1)]
    y_prim = [(y_data[i+1] - y_data[i]) / delta_x[i] for i in range(N - 1)]
    return x_prim, y_prim

x, y = zip(*a)  # a in an array you defined above
x_bis, y_bis = derivative(*derivative(x, y))
```

but if you want to get curvature as curvature of 2D line on plane (not a curvature of function) you need to divide it by *square root of third power of one plus squared derivative of y data* (`(1+y'^2)^(3/2)`) :) just as in:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature#Curvature_of_a_graph

probably you will need to make some interpolation, but if x-coordinates are equdistant - it would be much easier.

Comment: Thanks. In my case, the curve is representing price data. So (Y) values are float numbers, whereas (X) is days, hours or minutes. I looked at the article and there are many different forms of curvature calculation. Not sure which one I should be implementing.

Comment: if X is time - then it is actually a graph of a 1-variable function, not a 2D curve on plane. i think you should take the easiest - just the second derivative.

Comment: Thank you. So is this what the above function is doing? -> https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/c92d581fd7b8a66308bde64d64dcd8d71cc66ce0

Comment: this fraction method is the most complex. the simplest would be just the upper part of fraction. just |y''| - this is what i wrote in the answer. this is just an example of derivative for provided x_data and y_data, but the problem of computing derivative is a perfect subject for separate question. you will get plenty of better answers i think because i cant find it on stackoverflow

Comment: this could be useful too: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.gradient.html   https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html

Comment: Thanks! In the light of your post, the information on the Wiki and a further research on the topic, I have managed to get this working. I used the implementation provided here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28269379/curve-curvature-in-numpy I am attaching the result to the end of my questions as an EDIT. Thanks!